# how can we change the column to rows in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How can we make the column `SubInventory` to row in SQL Server from the following query? Here the products first column, then the subinventory in row wise with product details.

In this pic you can see subinventory as in column wise I need it in row wise

```
SELECT 
    BRCH.BranchName [BranchName],
    ASI.SubInventoryName [SubInventory],
    APRO.ProductName [Product],
    ASICT.TransactDateTime [DateTime],
    ASICT.ProductStock [Stock],
    ASICT.ProductStockInLocalCrrncy [Local Stock]
FROM 
    ALX_SubInventoryCashTransfers ASICT
INNER JOIN 
    ALX_Branches BRCH ON BRCH.BranchID = ASICT.BranchID
INNER JOIN 
    ALX_SubInventories ASI ON ASI.SubInventoryID = ASICT.SubInventoryID
INNER JOIN 
    ALX_Products APRO ON APRO.ProductID = ASICT.ProductID
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         BranchID, SubInventoryID, ProductID,
         MAX(TransactDateTime) AS MaxDate
     FROM 
         ALX_SubInventoryCashTransfers                            
     GROUP BY 
         BranchID, SubInventoryID, ProductID) SubASICT ON ASICT.BranchID = SubASICT.BranchID
                                                       AND ASICT.SubInventoryID = SubASICT.SubInventoryID
                                                       AND ASICT.ProductID = SubASICT.ProductID
                                                       AND ASICT.TransactDateTime = SubASICT.MaxDate
```

The current result is

[image]

In this pic you can see the subinventory in column, it is not a count or average or sum, it a name

I need the result to look like this

[image: Reult I need]

Comment: You need pivoting I guess. Can you show what output you need and a sample of data (not screenshot of data)?

Comment: @ gofr1 i had post an sample image of the out i need from the above querry

Comment: What is `Subln 1` etc? Products will be shown as row or Column names?

Comment: ie, Subinventory 1 / sub inventory 2 etc.... products in columns subIn 1 shows the stock of each

Comment: @SwethaVijayan there are dozens of questions on pivoting and the PIVOT/UNPIVOT commands. You'll find the answer faster if you search for them. For example gofr1 asked about the *fields* named `Subln`, not the titles. What are these? Sums, averages, counts?

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos  here there is no sum or average or any thing used onnly the values to show as i result i need image shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all your query results into `#temp` table, then do dynamic pivot:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
        @columns nvarchar(max)

SELECT @columns = (
    SELECT DISTINCT ','+QUOTENAME([SubInventory])
    FROM #temp
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

SELECT @sql = N'
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  [SubInventory],
            [Product],
            [Stock]
    FROM #temp
) as t
PIVOT (
    MAX([Stock]) FOR [SubInventory] IN ('+STUFF(@columns,1,1,'')+')
) as pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: how can we group by with branch name in pivot

Comment: Just add `[BranchName]` into `SELECT ... FROM #temp` part

Comment: that already i have done but when i put groupby inside or outside  it "shows Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PIVOT'."

Comment: You don't need any `GROUP BY` inside this SELECT part. Only `[BranchName]`

Comment: so where should i put this, Group by, to group the collection with branchName

Comment: Pivot groups data for you. If you need to group MORE - put into under PIVOT part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124191/discussion-between-swetha-vijayan-and-gofr1).

Comment: great answer sir, @ gofr1, 100% works , i cant agin upvote the answer after one upvote from me , other i will give to more than 1 upvote for u thanks, a great help from u

Comment: My pleasure! :)